# How to create an app-wide keyboard shortcut in a UWP app that supersedes any keydown handlers that children XAML elements have?

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, winui

For example: a uwp pivot automatically handles Ctrl+Tab. I want to create a custom app-wide keyboard shortcut that uses Ctrl+Tab. However, if my app is currently focused on a pivot control, then the pivot steals the shortcut keydown event.

What I have tried:
For testing purposes, I created a singleton class that handles CoreWindow.KeyDown events. I register some handlers. When I press Ctrl+Tab without focusing on any element, then the singleton class handles the event. But if I focus on a pivot control in my app and press Ctrl+Tab, then the pivot steals the event and the singleton class does not. How do I make it so the singleton class picks up the event and not the focused element?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to register the `KeyDown` event on `CoreWindow`. After testing, `Pivot` receives keyboard events earlier than `CoreWindow.KeyDown` events, so you can try to disable the corresponding keyboard accelerator in `Pivot`:

```cs
private void Pivot_ProcessKeyboardAccelerators(UIElement sender, ProcessKeyboardAcceleratorEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.Key==Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab && args.Modifiers == Windows.System.VirtualKeyModifiers.Control)
    {
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

By listening to the `Pivot.ProcessKeyboardAccelerators` event, we can prevent the default behavior when `Ctrl`+`Tab` is triggered (**args.Handled = True**).

However, it should be noted that because the event is prevented from further bubbling, the `CoreWindow.KeyDown` event will still not be triggered at this time.

You mentioned in the question description that you used a singleton to handle the event triggered by the shortcut. Then you need to directly call your processing method in the singleton in the code.

```cs
...
args.Handled = true;
CtrlAndTabHandle();
```

Thanks.